# Is the subjunctive used in "He could have been a doctor if he had gone to university"? Why?

Tags: gramática, verbos, subjuntivo, tiempos-verbales

When saying:

> He could have been a doctor if he *had* gone to university

In Spanish, would you use the subjunctive in 'had' resulting in the following?

> Habría sido un doctor si *hubiera ido* a la universidad

Why?

Comment: Para evitar la cacofonia de la oración, se podría cambiar por "Habría sido un doctor si hubiese ido a la universidad."